# Correct MySQL query needed to a "save to favorites" button

Tags: php, mysql

This question should have a simple solution but Im not quit sure what it is.
Basically I have two MySQL tables. The first is `products` and for simplicity lets just say it contains the field `product_id`. The second table is called `favorite_products` and it contains the fields `product_id` and `member_id`.

Again for simplicity sake lets say I Query the product table and in my while loop I echo out the following link

```
 <a href="#" data-Id="$product_id" class ="save" Id= "$button_status" >add to favorites<\a>
```

When the user clicks this link a click function inserts the given product into the `favorite_products` table along with the `member_id`.

My question how would I write a query that would check the `favorite_products` table against the products table to look for matches? I want to do this so that I can then change the look of the add to favorites link based on if the user has already favorited the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly...

When you select products list, you can JOIN favorites for a given member:

```
SELECT P.*, F.member_id IS NOT NULL AS is_favorite
FROM products AS P
LEFT JOIN favorite_products AS F
    ON (F.product_id = P.product_id AND F.member_id = #member_id#)
```

Just don't forget to replace `#member_id#` with actual number ;)

Let's say you have `product_id` and `product_name` fields in `products` table. The result will be like this (simplified JSON-style):

```
[
    {product_id: 15, product_name: "Product A", is_favorite: 0},
    {product_id: 16, product_name: "Product B", is_favorite: 1},
]
```

Comment: Btw, MySQL has just perfect manual, have a look at  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html